# When is the Hodge diamond concentrated in $H^{n,n}$'s?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex algebraic variety. The Hodge decomposition tells us that $H^n(X, \mathbf C) = \oplus H^{p,q}$.

Here is my question:

> For what kind of $X$ is $H^{2n}(X) = H^{n,n}$ for all $n$ (I don't
>   care about the odd cohomology groups $H^{2n+1}$)? Has this condition been studied in the literature?

Or a slightly more relaxed question: given some $X$, can one construct a related variety $X'$ so that the property holds for $X'$? Or, maybe, give bounds on $dim H^{2n} - dim H^{n,n}$ etc.

Thank you!

Comment: This condition holds whenever the derived category of coherent sheaves has an exceptional collection(odd H^* will be zero in this case). If you take a variety with an exceptional collection and blow it up at a point and it will still have this property.

Comment: See the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151341/

Comment: Cellular varieties have this property. But not only these. As for constructing a "related variety $X'$", I think there is no chance. What would you expect to get for a curve of positive genus?

Comment: As others say, it's very natural to ask that _all_ cohomology be in $H^{p,p}$, and therefore that the odd cohomology vanishes; I think it very strange to ask this only of the even cohomology.

Comment: @Sasha: For a smooth projective curve $H^0$ and $H^2$ are all right, and I don't care about $H^1$ (I also guess $H^1$ cannot be easily "modified"). So the condition is satisfied for a smooth projective curve.

Comment: @AllenKnutson: I agree, the condition might look strange. The motivation to neglect odd cohomology groups is since I want to focus on the (possible) image of algebraic cycles. But, of course, examples which satisfy the condition for even cohomology and whose odd cohomology vanishes entirely are also very welcom.

Comment: @DanPetersen: Thanks for the link. I am aware of (and motivated by) the connection to the Hodge conjecture. However I wanted to focus on unconditional examples.

Comment: One example where the even cohomology is spanned by algebraic cycles and the odd cohomology is nonzero is the moduli space $\overline M_{1,n}$ of $n$-pointed stable curves of genus one, which has odd cohomology for $n\geq 11$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more restrictive condition, which probably has been studied, is to look at varieties with Hodge level $\le 1$. This means that $h^{pq}=0$ unless $|p-q|\le 1$. If you assume the general Hodge conjecture, then this is equivalent to the motive being a summand of $\bigoplus C_i(n_i)$ for some smooth projective curves $C_i$. If just want examples, they are easy enough to find. Take your favourite  variety with cohomology generated by algebraic cycles (e.g. a toric variety, a flag variety…) and then optionally take the product with a curve.

I am a bit skeptical about the last two questions. If $X$ is a degree $d$ surface, then $\dim H^2 - h^{11}$ grows with $d$. I am not sure what you would take for $X'$ in such a case.